# Binding simple data using DataContext in XAML to code not working?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm learning WPF, I want to pass data from some textboxes to code:

```
<Grid Margin="0,0,10,43" Name="dataFrm">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0">Name</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">Code</Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">Categry Id</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="txtName" Text="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="162" Margin="0,0,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="txtCode" Text="{Binding Path=Code, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="162" Margin="0,0,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="txtCatId" Text="{Binding Path=CategoryId, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Width="162" Margin="0,0,0,10" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <Button  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="btnSave" Click="btnSave_Click" Width="142" Content="Save"/>
</Grid>
```

When I click save, I want to cast the retrieved data to a predefined class:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var productVm = (ClsProducts)dataFrm.DataContext;
    MessageBox.Show(productVm.Name);
}
```

ClsProducts:

```
public class ClsProducts
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

but the `DataContext` of `dataFrm` is `null`!

Comment: Why would it **not** be null? Did you set it somewhere?

Comment: Did you set the `DataContext` for your control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you set the `DataContext` property of the `Grid` or its parent window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ClsProducts();
    }
}
```